# What is a "middle class injury"?

Tags: jokes, figurative-language

From [Buzzfeed](https://www.buzzfeed.com/robinedds/i-dropped-fondue-on-my-blackberry?utm_term=.kwxO2DV2R7#.giaz7vB7ab) I found the following article

> **36 Truly Terrifying Middle-Class Injuries**
>
> 2. I spent the morning reproofing our Barbour jackets and now my forearm is sore #middleclassinjuries
>      — Kimberley (@KimMHayes)
>
> [image]
>   [image]

What is a **middle class injury**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to disagree with Andrew on this point

> The article **makes fun of people** who have tweeted or otherwise posted about "injuries" sustained while doing actual middle-class things, like burning their mouth on peppermint tea. The use of "terrifying" is meant to be facetious.

I thought it was clear from the image, the so-called *injuries* are very very mild, no one went to hospital, no one got seriously hurt. The cut finger doesn't even look as if it was cut, the bandage on the finger was not done by a doctor,  it was posted to raise a giggle, and  a laugh. The *mezzaluna*, mentioned in one of the tweets, is a type of Italian chopping knife whose blade is shaped like a *half moon*, and virtually unknown in the UK thirty years ago. The Tweeter, who is not Italian, probably owns a [mortar and pestle](http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/using-pestle-and-mortar-to-pound-mixture-of-herbs-picture-id75376352) too, because he makes his own pesto.

Barbour jackets, wooden sushi play sets, Applewood Smoked Cheddar, espresso machines, [Agas](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=aga&biw=1242&bih=580&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi35sXoksHRAhWFJsAKHTsoBq0Q_AUIBigB), lamb burgers,  Waitrose créme fraiche, Belvoir Ginger Cordials are just some of the items and food stuffs mentioned in the tweets. Apparently, if you buy or own one of these things in Great Britain, it says something about your [socio-economic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socioeconomic_status) status; i.e. you are a member of the British middle-class.

**The posters are British, and the "victims" are being self-deprecating, and pretentious on purpose, they are mocking themselves,** hence the hashtag #middleclassinjuries.

e.g. *Just tripped over an orchid.*

Was buzzFeed taking the piss? Did the person who compiled the list thought the tweets were genuinely amusing, and wanted to share? Did Buzzfeed get that the majority of  tweets were self-mocking?

I didn't find the tweets funny, not because you shouldn't laugh at silly things when wars, deaths, and famines are happening aaround in the world but because the messages weren't witty.

> **[self-mockery](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/self-mockery)**
>   the practice of making yourself appear silly to show other people that you have a humorous attitude towards yourself

Comment: But it doesn't make sense how did they think making themselves look injured would look funny? o.o

Comment: It's possible, I didn't read the article carefully since I have a strong disdain for that kind of thing.  If the tweets are self-mocking then the entire article might have been all in good fun.

Answer (score 1):

Spraining your wrist while closing the sliding door of your minivan?  Burning yourself on your coffee maker?

Ah, it's BuzzFeed.  I guess I was right.  A "middle-class injury" is meant as a joke, it's an injury sustained by someone who is in the middle class.

Take my examples.  A lower-class person would not be able to afford a minivan -- they'd use public transportation or some less expensive vehicle.  An upper-class person would have a driver or a nanny to take things from the car, and probably would drive something more "upscale" than a minivan.  Only someone in the middle class would have a minivan, and have to close the door while carrying groceries and managing kids, and so be likely to sprain something.

The article makes fun of people who have tweeted or otherwise posted about "injuries" sustained while doing actual middle-class things, like burning their mouth on peppermint tea.  The use of "terrifying" is meant to be facetious.

(In my opinion, most of these are not funny, and don't accurately describe the "middle-class".  But I don't think much of BuzzFeed, in general)

See also: ["First World Problems"](https://www.reddit.com/r/firstworldproblems/)

Comment: Sorry, I was editing while you posted your answer. Much to one's chagrin, irony and sarcasm tags are non existent. Agreed, the tweets are not funny, so +1 from moi.

Comment: See, that injury in the link is a good example of why the list is stupid.  As if the rich don't like to cook, or "lamb burgers" are strictly for the middle class?  Doesn't work for me.  Plus I don't find other people's pain to be funny.

Comment: Well... I don't know many families who would feed lamb burgers to their off spring... And River Cottage is definitely Waitrose shopping (posh British supermarkets) territory, lovely cooking, fresh food etc.    https://www.amazon.com/River-Cottage-Baby-Toddler-Cookbook/dp/1408807564

Comment: But I don't get how do you know what is considered "middle class"?

Comment: @OkamaKsakas  that's more a cultural thing than an English thing, plus it will also vary from country to country and even region to region.  In one place, it might be owning a small house and driving a minivan.  Somewhere else it might be eating meat for every meal.  Also, in the US, this kind of discussion can have uncomfortably racist tones, another reason I don't like it.

Comment: Ok but this isn't even funny, why are they making fun of people who are injured? even if it was middle class, or not. It's not like people are hurting themselves deliberately to be honest. I am sorry if this has gone off topic, but you said it was meant to be funny. But how? It's not funny in the slightest.

Comment: @OkamaKsakas  It's funny to some people.  Not to me.  Some people think it's funny when people complain loudly about hurt themselves in small ways, when there are so many other people in the world suffering much more.  I'm sure you have those kind of people in your own country?

Comment: @OkamaKsakas  So in contrast I was just listening to Michael Connell, an Australian comedian.  He was joking that he plays the harmonica but he can't play "the blues" because, to play the blues *correctly* you have to sound like you've suffered in your life.  So "real" blues musicians sing about not having money, or food, or shoes, etc.  But if he were to sing the blues he would sing "I can't get cell phone reception!"  "there was a line at the supermarket!" and so on.  Not really "suffering".

Comment: Ahh I got your point. Well Buzzfeed has a point actually, it's correct to be honest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51747/discussion-between-okama-ksakas-and-andrew).